# Run file until the output matches regular expression

Tags: regex, bash

I would like to write a bash expression that would run the file "a.out" until the output of the file is equal to "b\na" where "\n" is a newline.

Comment: Can you please post the strategy you've tried so far?  Are you facing any specific issue?

Comment: I am trying to run "a.out" that prints "a" from main() and "b" from a thread created in main(). Most of the time "b" follows "a" but sometimes it is the opposite. What do you mean by strategy?

Comment: You want to prove that thread execution is (for our practical purposes) asynchronous? Just google it, there's plenty of proof out there (and hapless Q&A sites flooded by questions about why this is so...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#/bin/bash

a.out | while :
do
    read x
    read y
    [[ $x == 'b' && $y == 'a' ]]  && break
    echo $x $y
done
```

Tested this in bash on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: This will rerun `prog` multiple times until the output is exactly these two lines (and I would use `case` for the comparison). My understanding is that the program should keep running until those two lines occur in the output in that order. OP, please clarify?

Comment: I have put this code in a shell file test.sh and run it. It outputs this line over and over again: "./sk.sh: line 6: prog: command not found". I have Ubuntu 13.04 as well.

Comment: My bad.  `prog` is meant to be your `a.out`.  I assumed that you wanted to run your code over and over again.  Looking at your explanation to the comment by Rishabh Sagar, it seems you want to possibly kill the process (`a.out`) when the output follows that pattern.  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes you may kill it but it is sufficient to only stop looking for it. Or you may output some message like "b\na found". I just want to demonstrate that "b\na" can happen sometimes, even though "a\nb" happens most of the time. I just tried your new program and it terminates instantly, so hopefully it works.

Comment: I'm thinking `while true; do case $(./a.out) in $'b\na' ) break ;; esac; done`

Comment: @tripleee Your command finishes almost instantly, which is what I expected. It probably works.

Comment: I like @triplee's solution.

Comment: I also think that the string to be searched should have `a\n\b\n`

Comment: @perreal: I assume you missed an `n` when you got `\a` in the expression.  The original requirement is that stop only if there is a `b` followed by an `a`.

Comment: @unxnut, yes was a mistake. but in ababab (with newlines) you have many b's preceding a's.

Comment: @unxnut I down-voted since initially it was wrong solution, so now I am reverting this

Answer (score 2):

This might also help you quantify your results:

```
let ab=0 ba=0
for (( i=0; i<1000; ++i )); do
  case "$(./a.out)" in
    $'a\nb') let ab+=1;;
    $'b\na') let ba+=1;;
  esac
done
echo "a\\nb: $ab times; b\\na: $ba times"
```

Comment: Wow this is great, thanks. I didn't think of quantifying it. It is much more demonstrative this way.

Comment: +1, nice synthesis! For what it's worth, `case` is nice (too) in that you don't need to quote the expression you switch on, but the double quotes are, of course, harmless.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on `Ubuntu 13.04`
`pcregrep` matches `b\na`.
the `-m` flag to grep causes it to exit on first match.

```
until ./a.out | pcregrep -M 'b\na' | grep -m 1 a; do :; done
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
./a.out | while read line; do
    [[ $s == 1 && $line == 'a' ]] && break
    s=0 
    [[ $line == 'b' ]] && s=1 
done
```

Overkill way:

```
mkfifo myfifo
./a.out > myfifo &
pp=$!
while read line; do
    [[ $s == 1 && $line == 'a' ]] && break
    s=0 
    [[ $line == 'b' ]] && s=1 
done < myfifo
kill $pp 
rm myfifo
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
./a.out | sed '/^b$/!b;:l;n;/^b$/bl;/^a$/q'
```

Translation: if the current input line does not match `^b$` (beginning of line, b, end of line) start over with the next input line; otherwise, fetch the next input line; as long as we get another `^b$`, keep reading, otherwise, if it matches `^a$`, stop reading and quit.

`:l` declares a label so we have somewhere to go back to in the while loop. `b` without an explicit label branches to the end of the script (which then starts over with the next input line).

Comment: Tried to run it on Ubuntu 13.04 with this result 
"sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown command: `^'"

Comment: Now it outputs "a\nb" every time it is executed. I wanted it to run a.out over and over again until "b\na" is on the output.

Comment: Then you want @unxnut's answer.

Comment: I just modified my answer to reflect my perception of his problem because someone downvoted my answer :-(